# Exclude methods in Sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

Is there a way to exclude specific methods in classes when analyzing with sonarqube? All I find is how to exclude files and modules.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you want to surround the methods with [marker comments and use exclusions](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/#header-3), the answer is no.

Comment: How? Could you please write here one example.

Comment: @G.Ann - SonarSource Team, the link provided is no longer available :(... is there an udpated link?

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam, thank for the update. I think it will be worth mentioning this link to give us an example --> https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonar-ignore-issues-by-block-not-working/27008/6

Comment: This documentation link is more specific: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/#ignore-blocks-within-files

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76722069/10435528 has an example