# How to exclude one go function from sonar check

Tags: go, sonarqube

My Go service need to pass Sonar check. There're some functions (like creating DB connection) that need to be ignored.

How can I force Sonar to ignore one function on Go service?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exclude methods in Sonarqube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39390003/exclude-methods-in-sonarqube)

Comment: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/#header-3